# Sinatra scope nomethoderror

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, sinatra

I am trying to making Sinatra application.

But now I have a bug I can't solved. So I want help.

When I entered /tasks?status=done, the application alerts

> NoMethodError at /tasks undefined method `status_is_done'

How can I fix the bug? Please show me any tips if you can.

Here is the Model code.

```
module Todo
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
scope :status_is, ->(status){where(status: status)}

scope :status_is_not_yet, ->{status_is(NOT_YET)}
scope :status_is_done, ->{status_is(DONE)}
scope :status_is_pending, ->{status_is(PENDING)}

NOT_YET = 0
DONE = 1
PENDING = 2

STATUS = {
    'NOT_YET' => NOT_YET,
    'DONE' => DONE,
    'PENDING' => PENDING
}.freeze

validates :name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 140}
validates :content, presence: true
validates :status, numericality: true, inclusion: {in: STATUS.values}


def status_name
  STATUS.key(self.status)
end
```

end
end

And Here is the Controller code.

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'haml'


require 'todo/db'
require 'todo/task'

module Todo
class Application < Sinatra::Base

set :haml, escape_html: true

configure do
  DB.prepare
end

configure :development do
  require 'sinatra/reloader'
  register Sinatra::Reloader
end

get '/' do
  redirect :tasks
end

get '/tasks' do
  @tasks = Task.order('created_at DESC')
  #statusによって@statusの値を変更
  if (@status = params[:status])
    case @status
    when 'not_yet'
      @tasks = @tasks.status_is_not_yet
    when 'done'
      @tasks = @tasks.status_is_done
    when 'pending'
      @tasks = @tasks.status_is_pending
    else
      @status = nil
    end
  end

  haml :index
end

end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
@tasks = @tasks.status_is_done
```

with

```
@tasks = Task.order('created_at DESC').status_is_done
```

Comment: Oh how nice. I was able to fix bugs. Why did I have bug?

Comment: Did this solve your problem? I guess scopes are supposed to be called for models rather than their objects.

Comment: I understood. Thanks for helping me!!

Comment: If this is the correct answer, it would be great if you accept it :)